# CLSLogv logs are not coming in Crashlytics

Tags: swift, ionic-framework, crashlytics

Its an Ionic app with some code written in native. Its uses [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) that for logging Crashlytics.

In the native part for iOS as well, we are trying to use Crashlytics to enable logging. However no matter what I try logs sent using `CLSLogv` aren't visible in dashboard.

Here is my code.

```
@objc(ImageUpload) class ImageUpload : CDVPlugin {
    var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

    //https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-logging-in-swift
    private func sendErrorToCrashlytics(error: String) {
        NSLog("Error in send error function is \(error)")
        CLSLogv("%@", getVaList([error]))
    }

    @objc(imageUpload:)
    func imageUpload(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
      registerBackgroundTask()
      func execute() {
        let db = SQLiteDatabase()
         var recToUpLoad: PayloadModel? = nil
         while(toCheck) {
           do {
             let record = try db.readValues() // THIS METHOD THROWS EXCEPTION
           } catch Exceptions.SQLiteError(let error) {
             self.sendErrorToCrashlytics(error: error) // IT COMES HERE AFTER EXCEPTION
           }
         }
       }
       DispatchQueue(label: "imageUploadPlugin",qos: .background).async 
       {
        execute()
       }
     }
   }
```

However `CLSLogv` is not visible at all in Crashlytics. However when I do `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().throwException()`
, I can see it in the dashboard.

Exceptions is `enum`

```
enum Exceptions: Error {
    case SQLiteError(message: String)
    case JSONError(message: String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it may help someone. Somehow I couldn't get `CLSLogv` to work. I ended up creating an NSError object and log that in `Crashlytics` in catch block.

```
catch Exceptions.SQLiteError(let error) {
   let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: error.message, "query": error.query]
   let errorObj = NSError(domain: "sqlite", code: 400, userInfo: userInfo)
   Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(errorObj)
}
```